# C# Double source of truth (Dictionary and Value item)

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

I was wondering in an simple system, for example you have an Dictionary where the Key is also needed in the class of the Value, is there any way to prevent this design pattern or we have to stay with this.

The example bellow will be easier to understand:

`Dictionary<Vector2, Region> regions = new Dictionary<>();`

```
class Region {

    private Vector2 position; // #This is the exact same value as the Key in the dictionary.

    public Region(Vector2 position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

```
var examplePos = new Vector2(0, 0);
regions.Add(examplePos, new Region(examplePos));
```

Could you give me your opinion on this, is it an error from myself, should I documentate myself on something in particular ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to use class a key for dictionary?

Comment: Not really, that works by default that. I'm looking to have the variable "position" only once. In the example it's set in the Dictionary but also in the Object Region (So it's in double, in Value and in Key)

Comment: I got it that you have dictionary and value instance both containing key. Usually it shouldn't be a problem, you just have to maintain it in two places. Otherweise you are looking for a better presentation of your data.

Comment: @Sinatr OK, That's not a big problem, there's no workaround. Just wanted to be sure

Comment: Can you tell why you want to achieve this, i mean any particular reason?

Comment: Sure, i'm trying to implement an World > Chunk (Region) system, where the world store those chunks in Dictionary based on their position.